# SQLException: ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenha uma conexão com banco de dados Oracle que faz uma inserção simples na base.

O processo estava funcionando, porém agora esta apresentando o erro abaixo.

```
2017-07-13 14:25:55.929 ERROR 12062 --- [nerContainer-21] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : monitorPool - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed.

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:444) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:407) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:416) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar!/:11.2.0.4.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95) ~[HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101) ~[HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341) ~[HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:193) ~[HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:428) [HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:499) [HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:112) [HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:97) [HikariCP-java7-2.4.11.jar!/:?]
```

Eu uso o Hikari como gerenciador de pool de conexão.

Aparentemente para ser um erro de espaço em disco do banco de dados.

Como faço para resolver tal problema?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00257.php

Comment: Eu tinha visto esse link mas não me ficou claro como executar a solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era realmente espaço do ARCHIVE do oracle que estava cheio. E segundo o DBA quando esse espaço está muito cheio o Oracle começa a rejeitar as conexões ocasionando o erro.

Foi feita a limpeza dos ARCHIVES e o erro parou de ocorrer